# Get Struct name without fetching package name or pointer

Tags: go

I have a very simple code like this:

```
package chain_of_responsibility

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type CustomerBalanceRequest struct{
    CustomerName string
    Balance int
}

type BalanceRequest interface {
    Handle(request CustomerBalanceRequest)
}

type HeadEditor struct{
    Next BalanceRequest
}

func (h *HeadEditor) Handle(b CustomerBalanceRequest){
    if b.Balance < 1000 {
        fmt.Printf("%T approved balance for %v request. Balance: %v\n", h, b.CustomerName, b.Balance)
        fmt.Printf("%v approved balance for %v request. Balance: %v\n", reflect.TypeOf(h), b.CustomerName, b.Balance)
        fmt.Printf("%v approved balance for %v request. Balance: %v\n", reflect.TypeOf(h).String(), b.CustomerName, b.Balance)
        fmt.Printf("%v approved balance for %v request. Balance: %v\n", reflect.TypeOf(h).Name(), b.CustomerName, b.Balance)

    } else{
        h.Next.Handle(b)
    }
}
```

On fmt.Printf lines, I want to print the name of HeadEditor type. I use various ways to get that and this is my result:

```
*chain_of_responsibility.HeadEditor approved balance for John request. Balance: 500
*chain_of_responsibility.HeadEditor approved balance for John request. Balance: 500
*chain_of_responsibility.HeadEditor approved balance for John request. Balance: 500
 approved balance for John request. Balance: 500
```

The problem is on first 3 Printf calls, I can get the name of type, but they include pointer and package name. Is there any way that I can get only "HeadEditor" without package name and pointer and of course other than string processing solution like removing * and package name from the result.

Comment: Have you considered implementing the Stringer interface?

Comment: Can you explain more? I mentioned looking for a solution other than string processing. I am asking if Go has a built-in non-String processing way for that.

Comment: Implementing the stringer interface is no more string processing than using fmt. What you would do is have HeadEditor implement the `String() string` method which can simply return the desired text, this method is then automatically called by fmt when used with the `%s` verb (not sure about the `%v` verb).

Comment: works with %v as well it seems https://play.golang.org/p/rERpIuKJVEy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close with the last one. As `Name()`'s documentation says:

```
// Name returns the type's name within its package for a defined type.
// For other (non-defined) types it returns the empty string.
```

You're getting the empty string back because while `chain_of_responsibility.HeadEditor` is a defined type, `*chain_of_responsibility.HeadEditor` is not. You can get the type out from the pointer type with `Elem()`:

```
// Elem returns a type's element type.
// It panics if the type's Kind is not Array, Chan, Map, Ptr, or Slice.
```

So, if it's not always going to be a pointer, you'll want to check first if it's a pointer or not before calling `Elem()`.

Or you could make your code a lot simpler (and probably faster) by bailing on reflection and just giving your types a method that returns whatever string you want to use for each type, like `Type() string`. You could then define a `Typer` interface to encapsulate that method.

Comment: Yes, so the solution is this:
fmt.Printf("%v approved balance for %v request. Balance: %v\n", reflect.TypeOf(h).Elem().Name(), b.CustomerName, b.Balance)